# Google Maps api3 - Not Printing Polyline Path

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm generating polyline path segments. They show up fine in the map, but when I print the map they are not included. Also each segment includes an icon, not being printed either.
I'm using the following jQuery script to print the map. Do I need to encode the lat/lng points?

```
var printMap = function() {
    var popUpAndPrint = function() {

        var container = $('#map-canvas');
        var width = 1200
        var height = 600
        var printWindow = window.open('', 'PrintMap',
            'width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
        printWindow.document.writeln($(container).html());
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
  };

  setTimeout(popUpAndPrint, 500);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

polylines (and markers too, except when you use the option `optimized:false` ) will be rendered via `canvas`-elements.

The drawing of these overlays will not result in a modification of the HTML of the canvas-element, you'll not be able to copy these elements with your approach.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the optimized to true for the icons, and they print. The print problem for the polylines, however, seems like it won't be solved. I tried parsing the canvas via `$("#map-canvas canvas").filter(function(){
 dataUrl.push(this.toDataURL("image/png"));
});` and get a security error.